# Python/Django datatable with pagination and checkboxes

Tags: python, django, checkbox, pagination, datatables

I'm new with python/django and i have a problem with selecting all objects from other pages, i can only select them from current page. Wish someone to help me..[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6NBE.png)

Heres my code:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def index(request):
    title = 'Tags'
    tag_list = Tags.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(tag_list, 10)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        tags = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        tags = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        tags = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'tag/index.html' , {'tags':tags, 'title':title})
```

js for checkboxes:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('selected');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
</script>
```

index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'tag:selected' %}" method="get">
  <table id="dt" class="table table-bordered table-hover responsive" style="text-align:center;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"></th>
         <th></th>
        <td>Name</td>
          <td>Frequency</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for tags in tags %}

      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  name="selected" value="{{ tags.id}}"></td>
          <td><a href="{% url 'tag:detail' tags.id %}"> <img src="{{ tags.tag_image.url }}" style="display:block;
width: 80px; height:80px; margin:auto;"></a></td>
        <td>{{ tags.tag_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ tags.tag_frequency}}</td>
      </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table><input class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right; margin-right:5%; margin-bottom:2%; margin-top:-3%; "type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>


<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if tags.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ tags.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ tags.number }} of {{ tags.paginator.num_pages }}
    </span>
    {% if tags.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ tags.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean? current page will only allow you to select other pages from the current page

Comment: i think i should be able to select all objects from datatable pagination pages.. not only current one

Comment: can you post a screenshot? as its hard to understand what you actually want to do

Comment: I did add picture there, i hope it helps.. so i wish those checkboxes to be saved when i would go to page 4.. and when i press submit button it would select all them to other html page..

Comment: ok. i got it. you cant do it like this, you need jquery and django session to hold up the data, then when you press submit the data will come from session

Comment: well would it be too much to ask you to show an example or something.. i dont really know how to do that..

Comment: ok i am giving you the steps in the answer, hope you can understand, rest you need to google by yourself and code